# Dark/Light Automatic Change

Tags: javascript, themes, auto, light

So I have this manual script for changing my forum from dark to light, however how to do it as a automatic setup from 6pm till 7am dark etc)

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.color-mode__btn').on('click', function (event) {
            let val = $(this).prop('classList');
            $('html').removeClass('darkMode lightMode');
            ips.utils.cookie.unset('darkMode');
            ips.utils.cookie.unset('lightMode');
            if ($(this).hasClass('light--hidden')) {
                $('html').addClass('lightMode');
                ips.utils.cookie.set('lightMode', true, true);
            } else {
                $('html').addClass('darkMode');
                ips.utils.cookie.set('darkMode', true, true);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Based on users timezone or your server? If user timezone, you need to check user time and get the information to use it with some condition to activate light or dark theme. Else, get the server time and use it to define theme of forum.

Comment: user timezone, im using IPS geolocation btw. but the question is what should I add to the code to make it auto change?

Comment: Nothing inside the click event function because you wanna an automatic theme loading. However, inside your ready function : 1) get user timer, 2) use information with some condition to define the good theme. ( change the class color )

Comment: thx, tried but no idea how to do it- its fine as tbh Im not a js guy...

Comment: lots to learn then,,,,,